# Translating recurring code snippets into function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, matplotlib

Well, hello.

I was just doing some plotting exercises today and figured that my code could use functions to make it more readable and accesible. However I'm still struggling with "translating" recurring patterns into a function. For example - some of my today's code looked like that:

```
plot = plt.figure(figsize=(50,25))
ch4_year = plot.add_subplot(241)
ch4_year.plot(ch4_ppb, 
         linewidth=1, linestyle='dashed',
         color='blue', label='CH4')
ch4_year.set_title('CH4 & N2O vs. Year',fontsize=32)
ch4_year.set_xlabel('Year (AD)')
ch4_year.set_ylabel('Concentration in ppb')
legend = plt.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True)

n2o_year = plot.add_subplot(241)
n2o_year.plot(n2o_ppb,
         linewidth=1, linestyle='dotted', 
         color='red', label='NO2')
legend = plt.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True)

co2_year = plot.add_subplot(242)
co2_year.plot(co2_ppm,
         linewidth=1, linestyle='dashed',
         color='black', label='C02')
co2_year.set_title('CO2 vs. Year',fontsize=32)
co2_year.set_xlabel('Year (AD)')
co2_year.set_ylabel('Concentration in ppm')
legend = plt.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True)

so2_year = plot.add_subplot(243)
so2_year.plot(so2_ppb,
         linewidth=1, linestyle='solid',
         color='green', label='SO2')
so2_year.set_title('SO2 vs. Year',fontsize=32)
so2_year.set_xlabel('Year (AD)')
so2_year.set_ylabel('Concentration in ppb')
legend = plt.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True)
```

How do I translate that into a function and does it even make sense to to use functions in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: It does make sense to use functions. You could make a `do_subplot` function, which uses a generic variable name for the subplot (e.g.`subplot` instead of `ch4_year`), and all the things which are different between the different plots e.g. `color` would be passed as arguments to the function. Where things are the same in most but not all of the plots, you could use a default value. For example, you could have a `do_labels` argument which was a `True` or `False` value defaulting to `True`, and use it in an `if` condition inside the function when drawing the labels, but pass in `False` for N2O.

Comment: BTW you have a typo in your label for the N2O plot ("NO2").

Comment: Thanks a lot! much appreciated